# How to Add Custom Meta Box to Products in woocoomerce Admin Section only

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

I'm building a new e-commerce site with wp woocommerce. I wanna add a custom meta box to products page in woocommerce admin mode only. I'm using a plugin to display the price of gold in terms of its purity. For that purpose I need to add a custom are with name and value textarea inputs on the product add/edit page.
I need a custom 2 meta boxes with one to enter the name and other to enter the value of that name(1 one)

The result I wanna is like this:

I tried with some few plugins and codes that are not giving the result what I expect. I added a code that works on post and pages, not on the products tab.

Comment: https://imgur.com/a/UqNd5J4

Comment: Try ACF plugin https://wordpress.org/plugins/advanced-custom-fields.

Comment: thank you sandra...i tried ACF but im not getting the result i want... Please refer this image link...https://imgur.com/a/UqNd5J4 the result i wanna is like the one shown in the image

Comment: Did you searched a bit? … see in [all this related answers](https://stackoverflow.com/search?tab=votes&q=%5bwoocommerce%5d%20add_meta_boxes)

Answer (score -1):

I advise you to use the **ACF(Advanced Custom Fields) plugin for WordPress**. With deliberately described [documentation](https://www.advancedcustomfields.com/resources). **In your case, you need to add a field to the product and call it in the product ID code using function:** 
`the_field($ selector, [$post_id], [$format_value]);`

[the_field function docs](https://www.advancedcustomfields.com/resources/the_field/)